# Редирект в админке Битрикса

Tags: битрикс, form, redirect

Доброго времени суток, всем!

Редактирую админку Битрикса. Есть проблема, что в разделе магазина: 
Цитата

> Магазин->Настройки->Экспорт данных

есть форма, которая при пустом action перекидывает в каталог вариантов экспорта. 
Если же писать явно код:

```
$APPLICATION->GetCurPage()
```

-текущий юрл, и привязки делать на событии субмита: 
Код

```
<form method="post" action="<?=$APPLICATION->GetCurPage()?>" name="xml_setup_form" id="xml_setup_form" onsubmit="return start()">
```

то форма также переводит в общий каталог, не исполняя события субмита.

В чем особенность Битрикса? И как заставить форму выполниться в том же окне без редиректов и переходов?

Смотреть картинки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А Вы action так и пишете: action="$APPLICATION->GetCurPage()"? Может быть, попробовать: action="<? $APPLICATION->GetCurPage(); ?>"

Comment: всяко пробовал). и пустой action.

Comment: Пропишите сначала путь явно без использования скрипта. Если будет работать - ищите проблему в том как прописываете путь скриптом. Если нет - значит дело в чем то другом. И попробуйте посмотреть лог запросов и ответов куда редиректы делаются и откуда - может помочь. Возможно сохранение и редирект через JS просто. Ну то есть когда форму сохраняете - данные AJAXом отправляются, а затем редиректы выполняется.

Comment: @AlexanderBragin, поддерживаю совет

Answer (score 1):

Ну уж если так то action="< ? echo $APPLICATION->GetCurPage()?>"  Этот метод возвращает URL, а не выводит. Так что функцию вывода обязательно  Только без пробела перед первым знаком вопроса.

Если вы делаете свой экспорт (надеюсь вы не правите штатные скрипты), посмотрите как это сделано в штатных.

Comment: Это да, я к сожалению, просто выдал вариант без тегов php. Суть такая, что все равно не работает. Мне нужно, чтобы форма отправляла данные и выполняла работу на той же страница, что и форма